# $U(n) \simeq \frac{SU(n) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_{n}}$ isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to proof the following isomorphism

$$U(n) \simeq \frac{SU(n) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_{n}}$$

So I'm using the first Isomorphism theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem

It's easy to show that the following map is an homomorphism:

$$f: SU(n) \times U(1) \rightarrow U(n): (S,e^{i\varphi}) \mapsto e^{i \varphi} S$$

But I'm having troube to show that:

$$Ker f = \mathbb{Z}_{n}$$

How am I supposed to do that ?

Comment: I assume by $\mathbb{Z}_n$ you mean the set of $n$'th roots of unity (there might be other subgroups isomrorphic to that after all).

Comment: Anyway, what can $S$ be if $f(S,x) = 1$?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a group with n elements for example $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ could be $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ or $\lbrace I,-I \rbrace$ but I'm not even sure though.

Comment: Then how can you expect to ever solve this? And as I mentioned, it is not enough to know what the group is up to isomorphism. You need to know it as a subgroup of the given group.

Comment: I don't know, I'm confused now..

Comment: Can you see the answer to my second comment?

Comment: No, that's actually my question

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: If you have a matrix $A$ and a scalar $x$, when can $xA$ be the identity matrix? What sort of matrix must $A$ be?

Comment: Well, I think it depends on x. A could be the identity and x could be 1 or A could be diagonal with $x^{-1}$ as elements of the diagonal

Comment: But det(A) as to be 1

Comment: Yes, what $A$ is will depend on $x$. But let's say $x$ is given. Can you determine those $A$ for which $Ax$ is the identity (let's just take arbitrary $n\times n$ matrices, not those in $SU(n)$ for now)?

Comment: It looks simple, but no..

Comment: Hint: Clearly $x\neq 0$. Try multiplying by $x^{-1}$ on both sides.

Comment: Ok so $A = I x^{-1}$ which is the diagonal matrix with $x^{-1}$ on the diagonal, right ?

Comment: Right, so $A$ must be diagonal with identical elements on the diagonal for such an $x$ to exist. Which matrices of $SU(n)$ satisfy this?

Comment: If $A \in SU(n)$ then $det(A) = 1$ then A has to be the identity ?

Comment: Now what about x ?

Comment: Not quite identity. Consider a matrix with the same $n$'th root of unity on all diagonal entries.

Comment: Yeah right, so we have 2 matrices ?

Comment: Which two? We have one for each $n$'th root of unity.

Comment: So is it $e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{n}}I$ where $k \in \lbrace 0,1,...,n-1 \rbrace$?

Comment: @Tobias, I admire your attempt at Socratic dialogue here. It seems to me that you are making a bit prgress also (+1 to Samuel). You could also consider posting a sequence of steps as a hint answer. That is, if that won't cramp your style :-). The system alerted mods for the number of comments. Our resident comment flagger may also already be on his way...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the heads-up (I have already accidentally moved this to chat by misclicking a few times, but I dislike doing that).

Comment: Great, so now we know what $S$ might be if $(S,x)$ is in the kernel. Given such an $S$, what will $x$ be?

Comment: $e^-{\frac{2 \pi i k}{n}}$ ?

Comment: Indeed. So now we know what pairs $(S,x)$ are in the kernel. So we just need to identify these with the group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ of $n$'th roots of unity.

Comment: So $Ker f = (e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{n}}I, e^{-\frac{2 \pi i k}{n}})$ and I have to show that $Ker f \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ ?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Any hint for this ?

Comment: Well, you have a pair of $n$'th roots of unity and you want to map this to some $n$'th root of unity. Hopefully there are two choices that seem "obvious" (and they both work).

Comment: If I take for example
$\phi : Ker f=(S,x) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{n}: (Sx)^{1/2}$
But this is not homomorph so it doesn't work...

Comment: If you have two things, and you only want one thing, what is the "naive" thing to do?

Comment: Multiply them ?

Comment: No, even more naively (let's assume you cannot do anything to combine the things).

Comment: Throw away one ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Show that this does indeed define an isomorphism.

Comment: The map would be $\phi : Ker f=(S,x) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{n}: \phi(S,x)= (x)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, except you have it called $\phi$ one place and $f$ another.

Comment: So we show:

$\phi((S1,x1)(S2,x2)) = \phi(S1,x1) \phi(S2,x2)$

And that's a bijection

Comment: Ok I have to go. I can write my own answer now, I'll do that later. Thank you very much for guiding my through this, sometimes it's better to try yourself with a little help, that's how you learn ! Thank you, you rock !

Comment: Don't forget to write an answer, so you can get feedback on that too.

Comment: Did it ! But I'm not 100% sure though

Answer (score 13):

I'm writing the answer to my question but I'm not completely sure though

## Intro

### What do we want to show ?

$$U(n) \simeq \frac{SU(n) \times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_{n}}$$

### Groups definition

- $U(n)$ = the group of $n\times n$ unitary matrices $\Rightarrow$ $U \in U(n): UU^{\dagger} = U^{\dagger}U = I \Rightarrow \mid det (U) \mid ^{2} = 1$
- $U(1) =$ the group of $1\times 1$ unitary matrices $\Rightarrow U(1) = \lbrace e^{i\varphi} \mid \varphi \in \left[ 0, 2\pi \right]  \rbrace$
- $SU(n) =$ the group of $n\times n$ unitary matrices with determinant 1
- $\mathbb{Z}_{n} =$ the cyclic group of n integers modulo n $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbb{Z}_{n} =$ the set $\lbrace 0,1,2,...,n-1 \rbrace$ with the operation of addition modulo n.
  \end{itemize}

### Isomorphism theorem

We use the first isomorphism theorem:

Let G and H be groups and let $f: G \longrightarrow G'$ be a group homomorphism. Then:

$$Im f \simeq \frac{G}{Ker f} $$

### What do we have to do ?

We have to do the following things:

1. Find a map $f: SU(n) \times U(1) \rightarrow U(n)$ and show that it's a homomorphism
2. Show that $Ker f = \mathbb{Z}_{n}$
3. Show that $Im f = U(n)$ which is equivalent to show that f is surjective

## We find and homomorphism between $SU(n) \times U(1)$ and $U(n)$

\begin{eqnarray*}
  f: && SU(n) \times U(1) \rightarrow U(n) \\
     && (S,e^{i\varphi}) \mapsto Se^{i\varphi} 
\end{eqnarray*}

$f$ is a homomorphism if :

\begin{eqnarray*}
  f((S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}})(S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}} )) = f(S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}})f(S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}} )&& \forall \varphi _{1}, \varphi _{2} \in U(1) \\
     && \forall S_{1},S_{2} \in SU(n)
\end{eqnarray*}

It's easy to show:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  f((S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}})(S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}})) &=& f(S_{1}S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{1}}e^{i\varphi _{2}} ) \\
     &=& S_{1}S_{2} e^{i\varphi _{1}} e^{i\varphi _{2}} \\
     &=& e^{i\varphi _{1}} S_{1} e^{i\varphi _{2}} S_{2} \\
     &=& f(S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}})f(S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}})
\end{eqnarray*}

## We show that $Ker f = \mathbb{Z}_{n}$

$$Ker f = \lbrace (S,e^{i\varphi}) \in (SU(n) \times U(1)) \: \vert \: f(S,e^{i\varphi}) = Se^{i\varphi} = e_{U(n)} = I \rbrace$$

### Let's find S

\begin{eqnarray*}
     e^{i\varphi}S&=& I \\
    S  &=&  e^{-i\varphi} I\\
    det(S) &=& det(e^{-i\varphi} I) \\
    1 &=& e^{-in \varphi} \\
    1 &=& \cos (n\varphi ) - i \sin (n \varphi)
\end{eqnarray*}

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{r c l}
\cos (n \varphi ) &=& 1\\
\sin (n \varphi ) &=& 0\\
\end{array}
\right.
 \Rightarrow n \varphi = 2k \pi \Rightarrow \varphi = \frac{2k \pi}{n} \quad \text{with} \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

So the matrices S are:

$$S = e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I \quad \text{with} \quad k \in \lbrace 0,1,...,n-1 \rbrace$$

### Let's find $e^{i\varphi}$

\begin{eqnarray*}
    e^{i\varphi}S&=& I \\
    e^{i\varphi}e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I&=& I \\
    e^{i\varphi}&=& e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

### Ker f

$$Ker f = (e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I,e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}}) \quad \text{with} \quad k \in \lbrace 0,1,...,n-1 \rbrace $$

### We show that Ker $f$ is isomorph to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$

We denote by $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ the cyclic group of integers modulo n.
Let's not forget that:

- The group law $\cdot$ of Ker f is given by:
  $(S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}})\cdot(S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}}) = (S_{1}S_{2},e^{i(\varphi _{1} + \varphi _{2})})$
- The group law $\cdot$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is given by:
  $k_{1} \cdot k_{2} = k_{1} + k_{2}$
  \end{itemize}

Let's show that Ker f is isomorph to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$

$$\phi: Ker f = (S,e^{i\varphi}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{n} : (e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I,e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}}) \mapsto k$$

#### $\phi$ is an homomorphism

$$\phi((S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}})(S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}})) = \phi(S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}}) + \phi(S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}})$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
    \phi((S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}})(S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}}))&=& \phi(S_{1}S_{2},e^{i(\varphi _{1} + \varphi _{2})}) \\
    &=& \phi (e^{-i \frac{2 (k_{1} + k_{2}) \pi}{n}} I,e^{i \frac{2 (k_{1} + k_{2}) \pi}{n}}) \\
    &=& k_{1} + k_{2} \\
    \phi(S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}}) + \phi(S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}})&=& (e^{-i \frac{2 k_{1} \pi}{n}} I,e^{i \frac{2 k_{1} \pi}{n}}) + (e^{-i \frac{2 k_{2} \pi}{n}} I,e^{i \frac{2 k_{2} \pi}{n}}) \\
    &=& k_{1} + k_{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

#### $\phi$ is injective

- $\phi$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow \forall \varphi_{1},\varphi_{2} \in \left[ 0, 2\pi \right] \: \text{and} \: \forall S_{1},S_{2} \in SU(n): \phi (S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}}) = \phi (S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}}) \Rightarrow \varphi_{1} = \varphi_{2} \: \text{and} \: S_{1} = S_{2}$
  \begin{eqnarray*}
      \phi (S_{1},e^{i\varphi _{1}}) & = & \phi (S_{2},e^{i\varphi _{2}})\\
      S_{1}e^{i\varphi _{1}} & = & S_{2}e^{i\varphi _{2}} \\
      e^{i(\varphi _{1} - \varphi _{2})} S_{1} & = & S_{2} \\
      det( e^{i(\varphi _{1} - \varphi _{2})} S_{1}) & = & det( S_{2} ) \\
      e^{in(\varphi _{1} - \varphi _{2})} & = & 1
  \end{eqnarray*}

$$\Rightarrow \varphi _{1} = \varphi _{2} \Rightarrow S_{1} = S_{2}$$

- We can also use the fact that $\phi$ is injective if and only if $Ker \phi = \lbrace e_{Ker f}  \rbrace = \lbrace (I,1)\rbrace$

$$Ker \phi = \lbrace (e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I,e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}}) \in Ker f \: \vert \: \phi(e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I,e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}}) = e_{\mathbb{Z}_{n}} =  0 \rbrace$$

$$\phi(e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I,e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}}) = k = 0 \Rightarrow Ker \phi = (e^{0} I,e^{0}) = (I,1)$$

#### $\phi$ is surjective

- $\phi$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}, \exists (e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I,e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}}) \in Ker f : \phi(e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I,e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}}) = k$
- Another way to show $\phi$ is surjective is by noting that fact that $\phi$ is an injective map between 2 finites sets with the same number of elements so $\phi$ is surjective

## We show that f is surjective

### How do we show that $Im f = U(n)$ ?

We want to show that $Im f = U(n)$ where: $ Im f = \lbrace Se^{i\varphi} \vert S \in SU(n), \varphi \in \left[ 0, 2\pi \right] \rbrace$

To do that, we can show that:

$$Im f \subseteq U(n) \quad \text{and} \quad U(n) \subseteq Im f$$

### $Im f \subseteq U(n)$

$$Im f \subseteq U(n) \Rightarrow \mid det (Se^{i\varphi}) \mid ^{2} = 1 \quad \forall  S \in SU(n), \forall  \varphi \in \left[ 0, 2\pi \right] $$

\begin{eqnarray*}
     \mid det (Se^{i\varphi}) \mid ^{2} & = & \mid e^{i n \varphi} \mid ^{2} \\
      & = & 1 ^{2} \\
      & = & 1   
\end{eqnarray*}

### $U(n) \subseteq Im f$

It's equivalent to show that: $\forall X \in U(n), \exists (Y,z) \in SU(n) \times U(1) \quad \text{such as} \quad f(Y,z) = Yz = X$

\begin{eqnarray*}
    X \in U(n)&\Rightarrow& \vert det(X) \vert ^{2} = 1 \Rightarrow det(X) = e^{i\theta} \equiv m \\
              &\Rightarrow& X^{\dagger}X = XX^{\dagger} = I \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Let's write X as: $X = zY = m^{1/n} Y$ where $Y = m^{-1/n}X$ and let's show that $Y \in SU(n)$ and $m^{1/n} \in U(1)$:

- $Y \in SU(n) \Leftrightarrow YY^{\dagger} = Y^{\dagger} Y = I$ and $det(Y) = 1$

  $$YY^{\dagger} = (m^{-1/n} X)(m^{-1/n} X)^{\dagger} = (e^{\frac{i\theta}{n}} X)(e^{\frac{i\theta}{n}} X)^{\dagger} = e^{\frac{i\theta}{n}} e^{\frac{-i\theta}{n}} XX^{\dagger} = I $$

$$det(Y) = det(m^{-1/n} X) = m^{-1} det(X) = m^{-1} m = 1 \Rightarrow Y \in SU(n)$$

- $m^{1/n} = e^{\frac{i\theta}{n}} \in U(1) $

Answer (score 2):

If I assume that x is just a scalar when I'm trying to find Ker f like I did with  Tobias Kildetoft using the nth roots of unity group. Isn't easier to assume directly that x can be written as $e^{i \varphi}$ ?

## We show that $Ker f = \mathbb{Z}_{n}$

$$Ker f = \lbrace (S,x) \in (SU(n) \times U(1)) \: \vert \: f(S,x) = Sx = e_{U(n)} = I \rbrace$$

### Let's find S

\begin{eqnarray*}
     xS&=& I \\
     S &=&  x^{-1}I
\end{eqnarray*}

Let $x^{-1} = y$. S is a diagonal matrix with $y$ as diagonal entries \

As $S \in SU(2)$ then

\begin{eqnarray*}
     det(S)&=& det(yI) \\
      &=&  y^{n} \\
       &=& 1
\end{eqnarray*}

#### $n^{th}$ roots of 1

How can we solve this equation ? We want to solve $y^{n} = 1$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Let's write both side of equation in polar form:

$$y^{n} = (r e^{i \theta} )^{n} = r e^{i \theta n}$$
$$1 = (r e^{i \theta} ) = 1 e^{i 0}$$

$y^{n}$ and $1$ are equal if and only if:

- $r^{n} = 1$. As r is positif, we have r = 1
- $n\theta = 0 + 2k\pi$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $\theta = \frac{2 k \pi}{n} $

We can visualize this geometrically. The points will lie on the unit circle and they will be equally spaced on the unit circle every $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ radians.

So our equation have $n-1$ different solutions as we go back to where we started once we reach $k = n$

So the $n^{th}$ roots of unity are given by:

$y = e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}}$ with $k = \lbrace 0,1,...,n-1 \rbrace$

So the matrices S are:

$$S = e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I \quad \text{with} \quad k \in \lbrace 0,1,...,n-1 \rbrace$$

It's easy to show that this form a group

### Let's find x

\begin{eqnarray*}
    xS&=& I \\
    xe^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I&=& I \\
    x&=& e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

### Ker f

$$Ker f = (e^{i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}} I,e^{-i \frac{2 k \pi}{n}}) \quad \text{with} \quad k \in \lbrace 0,1,...,n-1 \rbrace $$