# Is ${SU} (n)$ a normal subgroup of ${U} (n)$, precisely?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, manifolds, lie-groups, exact-sequence

[In Wikipedia  Unitary Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group#Properties), it says that
$$1\to \operatorname {SU} (n)\to \operatorname {U} (n)\to \operatorname {U} (1)\to 1.$$

However, we see that [this I understand]
$\operatorname {U} (n)$ is related to $\operatorname {SU} (n)$ and $\operatorname {U} (1)$ by
$$
\operatorname {U} (n)=\frac{\operatorname {U} (1)\times \operatorname {SU} (n)}{\mathbb{Z}_n}
$$
where ${\mathbb{Z}_n}= {\mathbb{Z}}/({n \mathbb{Z}})$, a finite Abelian cyclic group of order $n$. This is the case because both $U(1)$ and ${SU} (n)$ shares the same subgroup
$${\mathbb{Z}_n}=\{ \exp(\frac{2 \pi i }{n}j) \cdot \mathbb{I}_{n\times n}\}$$
where $j \in \mathbb{Z} \mod n$.

> If so, why is this true
>   $$1\to \operatorname {SU} (n)\to \frac{\operatorname {U} (1)\times \operatorname {SU} (n)}{\mathbb{Z}_n} \to \operatorname {U} (1)\to 1?$$
>   Is ${SU} (n)$ a normal subgroup of ${U} (n)=\frac{\operatorname {U} (1)\times \operatorname {SU} (n)}{\mathbb{Z}_n}$, precisely?

Comment: Some details are given in the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111766/un-simeq-fracsun-times-u1-mathbbz-n-isomorphism). It is simply the semidirect product, hence we obtain a (split) exact sequence.

Comment: $SU(n)$ is a kernel of the determinant homomorphism. Is this not enough justification for you?

Comment: As I said I already I know $U(n)=[SU( n ) \times U(1)]/Z_n$. I am asking which $SU(n)'$ and which $U(1)'$ they are in the exact sequence $1\to {SU} (n)'\to \frac{{U} (1)\times {SU} (n)}{\mathbb{Z}_n} \to {U} (1)'\to 1?$ Is that ${U} (1)'={U} (1)/Z_N$? or is that $ {SU} (n)'=PSU(n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The determinant mapping $A \mapsto |A|$ is a group homomorphism $U(n) \to U(1)$. Its kernel is $SU(n)$. So $SU(n)$ is a normal subgroup of $U(n)$.

Comment: do you happen can comment this as well, math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607058, I believe some version is true?

Answer (score 2):

Note $U(1)\times SU(n)$ maps to $U(n)$ via $(z,M)\mapsto zM$. The kernel $K$
is the set of $(\zeta^{-1},\zeta I)$ where $\zeta^n=1$, and is cyclic
of order $n$. Now $U(1)\times SU(n)$ maps onto $U(1)$ by $(z,M)\mapsto z^n$. This kills $K$, so is really a map $\phi$ from $(U(1)\times SU(n))/K$
to $U(1)$. Also, the kernel of $\phi$ is $H/K$ where $H=\{(z,M):z^n=1\}$.
Modulo $K$ each element of $H$ has a unique representation $(1,M)$
modulo $K$, and so $H/K\cong\{(1,M):M\in SU(n)\}\cong SU(n)$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I already I know $U(n)=[SU(n)\times U(1)]/Z_n=[SU(n)×U(1)]/Z_n$. I am asking which $SU(n)′$ and which $U(1)′$ they are in the exact sequence $1\to SU(n)′→U(1)\times SU(n)/Z_n→U(1)′→1$? Is that $U(1)′=U(1)/Z_n$? or is that $SU(n)′=PSU(n)$?

Comment: @wonderich:  I'm not sure what you mean by $SU(n)'$, but $SU(n)$ and $PSU(n)$ are non-isomorphic Lie groups.  For example, the first is simply connected and the second is not.  In case it helps, the composition $SU(n)\rightarrow SU(n)\rightarrow U(1)\rightarrow [SU(n)\times U(1)]/Z_n$ maps $SU(n)$ Lie isomorphically onto its image in $U(n)$.

Comment: do you happen can comment this as well, math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607058, I believe some version is true?